# How to fetch specific detail from p4 info command?

Tags: windows, perforce

I know there is p4 info which provides all details specific to the perforce workspace.
But i only want to get "Client name". Tried doing as "p4 info [-s Client name]" but its not returning anything.
Please suggest how shall i get specific detail rather then all info

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47579641/how-to-get-client-name-of-a-perforce-workspace-using-p4-info-from-python-sc

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-F` flag together with `-ztag` to get the field you want.

E.g.,

```
p4 -F "%clientName%" -ztag info
```

To learn the names of the different fields, simply run `p4 -e -ztag info`.