# How to get "Client name:" of a perforce workspace using "p4 info" from python script?

Tags: python, windows, perforce

I have a scenario where i need to have perforce workspace Client name information. Trying out with script as follows:

```
    import sys
    import subprocess
    cmd = "p4 info | grep" + """ "Client name" """ +""
    print ("p4 command is: ",cmd)
    p4 = subprocess.call(cmd)
    print( p4)
```

Where i get out put as :

```
    p4 command is: p4 info | grep "Client name"
    Usage: info [-s]
    Unexpected arguments.
    1
```

I tried doing as follows too but did not worked:

```
    import sys
    import subprocess
    p4_info = subprocess.call([sys.executable, "p4 info | grep "Client name""])
```

I actually want to fetch only Client name information. So, suggest me how i may have that. If there is another way of doing it please suggest. The script will be executed within the workspace and shall return the only Client name:

Answer (score 12):

Do:

```
p4 -Ztag -F %clientName% info
```

Comment: Cannot find any description of the `-F` option in Perforce docs for g-opts. Where did you find it?

Comment: I wrote it.  :D  It's an undoc feature so it doesn't show up in the normal docs, but I wrote up a blog post on it back when: https://www.perforce.com/blog/fun-formatting

Comment: This seems to work well on my Mac but on Windows it returns bogus information (it returns partial machine names, but not the machine I was issuing the command, some other Mac machines that I own - very weird). I have P4/NTX64/2017.2/1579154 on that Windows machine.

Comment: Since the "info" command doesn't return info about other client machines I'm gonna guess you're running a different command?  Try forums.perforce.com for support...

Comment: Looks like the article @Samwise linked to is now at https://portal.perforce.com/s/article/16565